What listener/event handler I can call after the joystick state changed
I’m new to C# and currently working on mapping joystick input to a slider in a WPF application using SharpDX.DirectInput. Is there an equivalent listener, similar to onStateChange() or onValueChanged() in Android, that I can use to detect when the joystick is pulled by the user?
The solution I found was actively using an infinite while loop to get joystick states, which is very costly, taking up the CPU all the time.
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using SharpDX.DirectInput;

namespace TestJoystick
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Joystick joystick;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Slider slider = (Slider )this.FindName("slider");
            

            // create joystick
            joystick = InitJoystick();

            // Poll events listener/callback here, instead of an infinite loop below


            //while (true)
            //{
            //    joystick.Poll();
            //    var datas = joystick.GetBufferedData();
            //    foreach (var state in datas)
            //        Console.WriteLine(state);
            //}
        }

        private void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox) this.FindName("textBox");
            textBox.Text = ((int) e.NewValue).ToString();
        }

        private Joystick InitJoystick()
        {
            // Initialize DirectInput
            var directInput = new DirectInput();

            // Find a Joystick GUID
            var joystickGuid = Guid.Empty;
            foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Gamepad, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
                joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;

            // If Gamepad not found, look for a Joystick
            if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Joystick, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
                    joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;
            }

            // If Joystick not found, exit
            if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No joystick/Gamepad found.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            // Instantiate the joystick
            Joystick joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joystickGuid);
            Console.WriteLine($"Found Joystick/Gamepad with GUID: {joystickGuid}");

            // Query all supported ForceFeedback effects
            var allEffects = joystick.GetEffects();
            foreach (var effectInfo in allEffects)
                Console.WriteLine($"Effect available: {effectInfo.Name}");

            // Set BufferSize to use buffered data
            joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;

            // Acquire the joystick
            joystick.Acquire();

            return joystick;
        }
    }
}


Joysticks provide continuous, not discrete, input axes - so there isn't really a "joystick state changed" event because the angle of the stick is always changing (based on its sensitivity). That's why games tend to poll the joystick sensors.

For example, android has listeners for continuous gestures, basically that listener will be triggered continuously until the users lift their finger

Gestures for a touch-screen are not like a joystick though: gestures have a defined end-point (or a timeout), joystick input is never-ending.

Can the IDLE state (no one is pull the device, the x, y are both 0 and the force is 0) be interpreted as an end? Once there is a force applied on the joystick, something is triggered and once it returns back to IDLE (no force), the event is end

No such functionality exists in Windows, as far as I know.

I see. Thanks for your comments! Really helpful!
